# CAML query using DateRangesOverlap does not respect CalendarDate when using year

Tags: calendar, caml, recurring-events

I've seen numerous articles on how to get recurring events for the year, month, week or day. However, it appears that when using `<Year />` the `CalendarDate` in `QueryOptions` is ignored.

In the below code, if I replace `<Year />` with `<Month />` then it respects the `CalendarDate` but with `<Year />` it does not.

Any idea why?

```
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name='Title' />
    <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
    <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
    <FieldRef Name='Location' />
    <FieldRef Name='Description' />
    <FieldRef Name='fRecurrence' />
    <FieldRef Name='RecurrenceData' />
    <FieldRef Name='fAllDayEvent' />
</ViewFields>
<Query>
    <Where>
        <DateRangesOverlap>
            <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
            <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
            <FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'>
                <Year />
            </Value>
        </DateRangesOverlap>
    </Where>
    <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
    </OrderBy>
</Query>
<QueryOptions>
    <CalendarDate>2018-01-01T12:00:00Z</CalendarDate>
    <RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>v3</RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>
    <ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>
</QueryOptions>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now and Year don't honour the CalendarDate property whereas others do honour it. See my article about it http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2015/05/sharepoint-recurring-calendar-events.html

Comment: Have you noticed that `CalendarDate` is not honour it even for `<Month />` in a DVWP?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan, I haven't checked that.